# How to solve $\int_0^x f(t) dt = g(f(x)) $?

Tags: calculus, closed-form, paradoxes

How to solve an equation of this type :

$$\int_0^x f(t) dt = g(f(x)) $$

for a given function $g$.

Im not so good with differential equations and integral equations.

I know how to solve $h'(x) = j(h(x)) $ in general and some approximations of specific cases of $k'(x) = k(l(x))$. But even my knowledge of those is limited.

However for this $$\int_0^x f(t) dt = g(f(x)) $$ I do not even know how to begin.

It seems very fundamental and simple though so my intuition assumes there must be a way.

I considered differentiating both sides but that got me to

$$ f(x) = g'(f(x)) f'(x) $$

Many thanks !

Comment: Left hand side is actually just $f(x) $.

Comment: Notice $g(f(0))$ must be $0$.

Comment: As @CameronWilliams pointed out, the LHS should be $f(x)$ so the simplification was not right.

Comment: I don't see why an easy form needs to exist here. Just pretend $g(x) = \sin x$, then you have $f = f'\cos f$ a highly nonlinear differential equation.

Comment: The OP is asking for closed-form solutions because the equation seemed "simple", but I don't think it is necessarily simple, see my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F(x):=\int_0^xf(t)dt=g(dF/dx)$ so, if $g$ has a functional inverse $g^{-1}$,$$dF/dx=g^{-1}(F)\implies x+C=\int dx=\int\frac{dF}{g^{-1}(F)}$$with $C$ an integration constant. In theory, this obtains $x+C$ as a function of $F$, say $h(F)$. If $h$ is invertible, $F(x)=h^{-1}(x+C)$.

Comment: Thank you !
I wonder why I got the wrong answer though ... 
Why did differentiating both sides not get anything done ?

Comment: @mick differentation doesn't do very much to address the fundamental difficulty in solving for $f$, which is that you've got one of the $f$ values inside the argument for $g$. At some point, you're going to need $g^{-1}$, or an equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

As you wrote,
$$ f(x) = g'(f(x)) f'(x)$$
That is, $y = f(x)$ satisfies the differential equation
$$ \dfrac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y}{g'(y)}$$
at least when $g'(y) \ne 0$.
For $x=0$ we have $g(y(0)) = 0$.  Depending on $g$, this may have no solution, or one, or several.    If it happens that $g(0) = 0$, one solution of the integral equation is $f(x) = 0$.

The differential equation is separable, with solutions in implicit form

$$\int \frac{g'(y)}{y}\; dy = x + c$$